# Quiero agregar una imagen mediante código al PictureBiox C# con SAP B1 SDK

Tags: c#, sap, sdk

Buen día foro quisiera de su ayuda.

Ya intente varias opciones y no me funcionan no me aparece en el formulario:

```
        //string pic= "c:\\Tmp\\DC.jpg";
        //PictureBox2.Picture.Contains(pic);
        //PictureBox2.Item.Specific.Equals(pic);
        //PictureBox2.Item.Specific.Equals(new Bitmap("c:\\Tmp\\Menu.bmp"));
        PictureBox2.Item.Specific.Equals(true);
        PictureBox2.Picture.Contains(@"c:\Tmp\DC.jpg");
```

O si hay alguna forma de mezclar un picturebox de C# al SDK de SAP.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta de esta manera:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("c://Tmp//DC.jpg");
```

Verifica que la ruta y el nombre del archivo estén con las minúsculas y mayúsculas correspondientes.
Saludos

Comment: Lo intente pero no funciono =(